# How to use Predict function with constraints on the output?

Tags: neural-networks

I have trained the Predict function with Method as "NeuralNetwork" to learn a function of an angle 0 < theta < 2 Pi, with period 2 Pi (the function returns a positive real number). I had to include training data from all quadrants in order to do this. I got an excellent fit to the analytical formula with 100 training examples. But imagine I have training data available only in the first quadrant and I know some constraints that the output of the function should obey in the remaining quadrants, can I use these constraints in Predict to get a better fit in the remaining quadrants? How do I do this? Basically I could not find any code that allows Predict to come with qualifiers of this kind.